# Create layerGroups by option value in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a JS array of markers and would like to create layerGroup objects based on icon value.

arrayMarkers = [marker1, marker2, marker3, marker4, marker5, marker6];

arrayMarkers content by line (markers ordered by icon):

```
marker1 = L.marker ([4.8,44.7], {icon :’http://…icon_A.png’})
marker2 = L.marker ([4.1,44.2], {icon :’http://…icon_A.png’})
marker3 = L.marker ([4.5,44.9], {icon :’http://…icon_B.png’})
marker4 = L.marker ([4.2,44.5], {icon :’http://…icon_B.png’})
marker5 = L.marker ([4.2,44.5], {icon :’http://…icon_B.png’})
marker6 = L.marker ([4.9,44.7], {icon :’http://…icon_C.png’})
```

Goal :
arrayLayerGroup = [layer1, layer2, layer3];

arrayLayerGroup content:

```
layer1 = L.layerGroup ([marker1, marker2])
layer2 = L.layerGroup ([marker3, marker4, marker5])
layer3 = L.layerGroup ([marker6])
```

I have tried this code, optionIcon brings back 'http://...icon_A.png' as expected, but have no clue how to compare values from same array. I can't compare line by line as coordinates are always different:

```
var j=1;
for (i=0; i<arrayMarkers.length; i++){          
var optionIcone = arrayMarkers[i].options.icon.options.iconUrl;
var optionIcone2 = arrayMarkers[j].options.icon.options.iconUrl;
    if (optionIcone !== optionIcone2){
        var layer = L.layerGroup([arrayMarkers[i]]);
        arrayLayerGroup.push(layer);
        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to admit that I have trouble understanding your request. The data sets as you expose them are very confusing, I can't seem to figure out their connection. What are you trying to compare exactly, based on what condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example using [Lodash `groupBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy):

```js
// Group the Markers by iconUrl
var markersGroupedByIconUrl = _.groupBy(arrayMarkers, "options.icon.options.iconUrl");

// Convert each group of Markers which have same iconUrl into a Layer Group
var arrayLayerGroup = Object.values(markersGroupedByIconUrl)
  .map((listOfMarkers) => L.layerGroup(listOfMarkers));
```

Comment: It works! I will now study the lodash doc (didnt know it before) to better understand your code syntax.  Thanks a lot.